# PL/SQL Oracle Package error when executing functions

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql-package

The package compiles well, but when executing the functions, it gives the following error "'SEARCH FOR_EMP_NO' is not a procedure or has not been defined" what is the problem? I think I am committing some problem with the ver_emple procedure. I have to pass the record to it to display an output text as in the example and I don't know how to do it.

```
/* Cabecera o especificación del paquete */
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE buscar_emple2
  AS
  TYPE t_reg_emple IS RECORD(emp_no emple.emp_no%TYPE, 
                              apellido emple.apellido%TYPE, 
                              oficio emple.oficio%TYPE, 
                              salario emple.salario%TYPE, 
                              dept_no emple.dept_no%TYPE
                              );
                              
  FUNCTION busca_por_emp_no(v_num_emple emple.emp_no%TYPE)
  RETURN t_reg_emple;

  FUNCTION busca_por_ape(v_apellido emple.apellido%TYPE)
  RETURN t_reg_emple;

  PROCEDURE ver_emple;
END buscar_emple2;


/* Cuerpo del paquete */
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY buscar_emple2
AS
vg_emple t_reg_emple;

FUNCTION busca_por_emp_no(v_num_emple emple.emp_no%TYPE)
RETURN t_reg_emple
  IS
  BEGIN
    SELECT emp_no, apellido, oficio, salario, dept_no
    INTO vg_emple
    FROM emple
    WHERE emp_no = v_num_emple;
    RETURN vg_emple;
    ver_emple;
END busca_por_emp_no;

FUNCTION busca_por_ape(v_apellido emple.apellido%TYPE)
RETURN t_reg_emple
  IS
  BEGIN
    SELECT emp_no, apellido, oficio, salario, dept_no
    INTO vg_emple
    FROM emple
    WHERE apellido = v_apellido;
    RETURN vg_emple;
    ver_emple;
END busca_por_ape;
  
  PROCEDURE ver_emple
    IS
    BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(vg_emple.emp_no|| '=======' ||vg_emple.apellido|| '=======' ||
                         vg_emple.oficio|| '=======' ||vg_emple.salario|| '=======' ||vg_emple.dept_no);
    END ver_emple;
  
END buscar_emple2;


EXECUTE buscar_emple2.busca_por_emp_no(7839);

EXECUTE buscar_emple2.busca_por_ape('SALA');
```

[image]

Comment: Who knows? Nothing - in code you posted - suggests that SEARCH FOR_EMP_NO is ever being used, so that's really a mystery.

Comment: I think the error message was put through a translator, busca_por_emp_no = searchfor emp no

Answer (score 1):

The output you have shared is the desired output, not the actual one you got. Running error messages through a translator is fine but note that some of it won't make any sense if you translate names of thing that haven't been translated in your actual code.

---

Edit- Second attempt at guessing from your translated error.
You have defined `busca_por_emp_no` as a FUNCTION not a procedure. In order to execute it you have to return it into something. You've defined it so that it returns a custom type. You would either change it's definition to be a procedure (with no return clause) or call it like you would a function:

```
declare
  myVar buscar_emple2.t_reg_emple;
begin
  myVar := buscar_emple2.busca_por_emp_no(7839);
end;
/
```

---

(This was my first guess as this was most striking about your code)

Your problem is you didn't actually send the PL/SQL packages to the databases to compile, you must end both the package specification and the package body definitions with a `/`
e.g

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE buscar_emple2
  AS
  TYPE t_reg_emple IS RECORD(emp_no emple.emp_no%TYPE, 
                              apellido emple.apellido%TYPE, 
                              oficio emple.oficio%TYPE, 
                              salario emple.salario%TYPE, 
                              dept_no emple.dept_no%TYPE
                              );
                              
  FUNCTION busca_por_emp_no(v_num_emple emple.emp_no%TYPE)
  RETURN t_reg_emple;

  FUNCTION busca_por_ape(v_apellido emple.apellido%TYPE)
  RETURN t_reg_emple;

  PROCEDURE ver_emple;
END buscar_emple2;
/


/* Cuerpo del paquete */
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY buscar_emple2
AS
vg_emple t_reg_emple;

FUNCTION busca_por_emp_no(v_num_emple emple.emp_no%TYPE)
RETURN t_reg_emple
  IS
  BEGIN
    SELECT emp_no, apellido, oficio, salario, dept_no
    INTO vg_emple
    FROM emple
    WHERE emp_no = v_num_emple;
    RETURN vg_emple;
    ver_emple;
END busca_por_emp_no;

FUNCTION busca_por_ape(v_apellido emple.apellido%TYPE)
RETURN t_reg_emple
  IS
  BEGIN
    SELECT emp_no, apellido, oficio, salario, dept_no
    INTO vg_emple
    FROM emple
    WHERE apellido = v_apellido;
    RETURN vg_emple;
    ver_emple;
END busca_por_ape;
  
  PROCEDURE ver_emple
    IS
    BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(vg_emple.emp_no|| '=======' ||vg_emple.apellido|| '=======' ||
                         vg_emple.oficio|| '=======' ||vg_emple.salario|| '=======' ||vg_emple.dept_no);
    END ver_emple;
  
END buscar_emple2;
/
```

You should receive a message if they were able to be compiled successfully, if it errored then check the compilation error and fix that.

```
show errors
```

Is the command to get errors if you receive a compilation error. I'm not going to create my own tables just to check if you don't have other typos in your code.

Comment: The code compiles fine, the problem is when I run the package functions: EXECUTE buscar_emple2.busca_por_emp_no(7839);

Comment: I've had another read of your whole problem and have spotted the other big problem, the error message makes it a little obvious - you haven't created a procedure, you created a function. I've edited my answer to include this and how you would call your function. It would be even easier to make it a procedure

Comment: There's another bug in the code. Both functions include calls to the procedure `ver_emple`. However in both cases the call comes after the RETURN clause, so the procedure is never executed. Any code after a RETURN call is unreachable.

Comment: Nice spot, my eyes consistently ignore that. Enabling pl/sql compiler warnings would alert you to unreachable code like this, well worth the additional spam IMO.